# Deleted old videos

Tags: zune, video

Today I noticed that I don't have all old videos on my phone as well as in Zune gallery. I do have pictures.

Is it possible that OS deleted some old videos to get some free space?  How is possible that all my old videos are gone? I can understand that phone could delete them but PC doesn't have them as well. Does it mean that someone had to delete them? Can I recover videos?

Comment: Were they videos which you uploaded through Zune, or videos you made using the phone's camera?

Comment: Made by phone's camera.

Comment: Are you sure that... Nobody accessed your phone or computer? You didn't connect the phone to the computer? You don't have wireless sync enabled? You've delete / move them on one of both such that it got synchronously deleted / moved on the other thing? Have you tried searching your whole computer drive for the videos?

Comment: There is no videos on the PC. There is a slight chance that someone access my PC and deleted them and changes are mirrored.

Comment: Have you tried recovery (like I'm suggesting in my answer)? Or does that also not help?

Comment: Files were overridden (at least what Recuva claims). I'm 90% sure that someone deleted them on 11 may.

Comment: @lukas: What makes you think that?

Comment: I linked up some facts. Elementary.

Answer (score 1):

Data loss is a sad thing, the first thing you should do is attempt to see if you can recover it with [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or paid software like [WinHEX Forensics](http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/). These can all find back stuff that has been deleted from the computer (if they weren't securely deleted or overwritten, which is most of the times the case).

If that doesn't work out, you might want to see if they somehow moved to another place.

If not, forensics labs are a last resort but they cost tons of money...

Answer (score 0):

Videos are stored with images in the same folder on the PC. Open your File Explorer then go to Pictures > "Name of your device" > CameraRoll

Once you have this folder open, the videos you've recorded will be everywhere. To see all your videos rearrange the folder to show you them. To do this drop down the icon that has a little down arrow, this contains different ways to view folder contents. Select "Details". This gives you all your photos/videos in a list. Now just Click the header that is labeled "Name". This will arrange all your photos and videos by file type because the phone names videos in a special way.

Now click "Name" again, and all your videos will be on top.

I do know you can set Zune to remove videos from your phone, but it will always place the video in this folder before deleting. Good luck.

Comment: Thx, but I do know how to view videos. The problem is someone deleted them from my PC and as a result Zune deleted them from the phone.

Comment: Aww man. Yeah thats going to put a kink in things. I would at least turn off any auto-defrag maintenance you have scheduled. At least you can prevent overwrite if you intend on salvaging. This is a PC recovery problem now =/